# Aws EC2 instance running out of space without apparent reason

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I have an Amazon EC2 instance with two docker containers that gets out of space every 20/25 days.
`Filesystem    Size    Used    Avail    Use%`

`/dev/xvda1    50G     40G      10G     80%` 

Already tried `du -hs * | sort -h` in many folders but couldn't find big folders or something like it.
Is there any other way to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not server administration issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Move your question to https://serverfault.com/. Tip: try `df -h`(from anywhere).

Comment: I recommend https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try over those.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by the extensive logging done by the Docker container, if you use the following command:

```sh
docker logs [container_id] | wc -l
```

You will see that the container is filled with logs. Imagine if all of this are stored in memory, of course the EC2's memory will be exhausted too right? Not really because the OS redirects not-so-used memory contents to the machine's swap. You can check if my guess is right using the command below:

```sh
grep Swap /proc/meminfo
```